# Abbreviate names using regular expressions under character constraints

Tags: regex

I want to abbreviate people's names using regular expression replacements, and below is the guideline.

- The names are seperated the word `and`.
- There is a unique comma `,` in every name, which seperates the last name and the first name.
- For each part of the first name, keep only its initial letter.
- Remove all commas `,`, dots `.` and hypens `-`.
- Replace every word `and` by the hypen `-`.
- Remove all the spaces .

Below is a list of examples of the abbreviation of single names.

- `Gelfand, Israel` -> `GelfandI`
- `de Giorgi, Ennio` -> `deGioriE`
- `Jones, Vaughan Frederick Randal` -> `JonesVFR`
- `Serre, Jean-Pierre` -> `SerreJP`
- `Siegel, Carl L.` -> `SiegelCL`
- `Piatetski-Shapiro, Ilya` -> `PiatetskiShapiroI`

Here is an example of the abbreviation of a list of names.

```
Gelfand, Israel and de Giorgi, Ennio and Jones, Vaughan Frederick Randal and Serre, Jean-Pierre and Siegel, Carl L. and Piatetski-Shapiro, Ilya
->
GelfandI-deGioriE-JonesVFR-SerreJP-SiegelCL-PiatetskiShapiroI
```

It is quite easy to do it using a finite chain of regular expression replacements. However, I encountered some additional constraints.

- It is not allowed to use any of the four characters `/\[]`.
- The empty string is not allowed.

In particular, these two contraints imply that:

- Escape is not possible;
- It is not trivial to remove any matched patterns, especially the dots `.`.

I would like to know if it is possible to do it under these constraints. I am particularly interested in regular expressions in Java, but any dialects are welcomed.

Comment: Have you made any effort yourself to solve this problem?  If so, can you include it in your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I already spent a lot time on it, and I am embrassed to admit that I have no clue at all how to solve it. I feel that some complicated lookaround is neccesary.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I cannot think of any language/tool that can easily overcome the difficulty of the lack of `/\[]`. At the end, I need to use the regex in Java. But, now, I am more interested in solving it in any language/tool than using it.

Comment: are you being forced?

Comment: @HariLubovac Yes, unless I want to do some reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex pattern seems to be working:

```
(?<=[A-Z])(?!.*,)[a-z]*\.?|[, -]
```

### Demo

Comment: Unfortunately, `\[]` are not allowed.

Comment: Not homework. I am developing some software, and I need to submit two strings, a pattern string and a replacement string to a black box that I have no control at all. The black box will strip those four characters, and raise an exception whenever an empty string is received. By the way, your solution also uses an empty string, and it does not work for the list of names.

Comment: My regex pattern works for all your sample data.  If there be some other edge case, then you should have included that as well.

Comment: It does not work for the long example, and it violates the constraints.